# Can't find the error exactly what or where it is in Logcat in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, game-engine, andengine, game-physics

I'm developing 2d games on Andengine for Android platforms. I'm getting an error but Eclipse doesn't show where or what it is. Can you help me to find it or how can I track the error?  [You can see the error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afcxa.png)

Regards

Answer (score 0):

put a:

```
try { } catch () { }
```

for your code and print Exception Messages as Toast, or in Log.

Note: your screenshot not obvious at all.

Comment: I don't know which code or code part produces this error. So I don't know where to put try catch.

Comment: you can put try catch for the whole code, when Exception happens, the handler will show you the Exception message, the Class where this exception happens, and the line number inside the class.  


Try to divide the code into sub parts, comment some of them and run other, still do this from beginning of code, until you find the problem, 

also, read about breakpoints

Answer (score 0):

Red error is key, fatal error 11, best I can do is to say that appears to be related to a datethread. Does this help you pin point the code? I did search for fatal error 11 on AndEngine and there are discussions, but not directly related to date thread.